# T-SQL on Azure Timeout when executing via SMO

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, smo

I've been banging my head for a few hours.  Whenever I try to execute a long query in SMO to my SQL Azure database i get a timeout after about 60 seconds.  When i execute the same long query on my local databases, I don't get the timeout error.  Thereby, i think the configuration has to be somewhere in Azure but i dont know where.  Any help would be appreciated.

The error message i get is:
Msg 64, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.)

A screenshot of my connection setting:
Im unable to post it here but here is a link.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHpZz.jpg

Comment: could you paste some screenshots ?

Comment: Screenshots of what?  If I knew where the configuration was to take the screenshot, then I wouldn't need to ask the question.

Comment: time out screenshot ?

Comment: can you share how you're executing the queries with SMO? and how you are establishing a connection?

Answer (score 0):

Please try overriding the default timeout value in your connection string, the default timeout value is 15, it's too short for connections that depend on internet. The recommended value is 30.

```
serverConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=tcp:mysernamename.database.windows.net,1433;User ID=user@server;Password=password;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;";
```

check [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-connect-central-recommendations/#connection-recommendations) for details.